# TypeError: Object expected at eval code (eval code:1:1) on Jscript for Crm Dynamics 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

When add this code in a form (OnLoad event), i receive this error :

> TypeError: Object expected at eval code (eval code:1:1)

```
function OnAlert()
{
//Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('message');
window.alert('ok');
}
```

Anyone help ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your form onload configuration?

Comment: Thanks Ark. I detect the issue and fixed. The error is very silly. When add .js on event i wrote the function name included "()". When the correct is without it.